# Best way to achieve Conversation view for mail folder using Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook, office365api, outlook-restapi

I would like to use the Outlook REST API to display the messages in a mail folder and group messages by conversations, like you have in any modern webmail.

For example with `inbox`, I would request using a first query such as `<mailuri>/inbox/messages?$select=ConversationId` (by default it is reverse chronological order)

It is not sufficient to group this request results by `ConversationId` because some emails may not be in `inbox` (think of `sentmails`) or they may be paginated and not returned in the first page.

Consequently, for each distinct `ConversationId` I need to perform another REST request, for retrieving participants or simply counting the emails in the conversation. I may use the new [batch request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/batch-outlook-rest-requests) to do this.

There are a lot of requests involved. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: This topic as lead to a dedicated UserVoice feature request, consider upvoting https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18765490-be-able-to-fetch-mails-by-conversations-in-folde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've probably realized the REST API doesn't directly provide a way to work with conversations as an entity. This is something that we have on our roadmap to improve.

With the current state of the API what you're describing is basically the right approach. You could possibly defer the second request to "fill in" a conversation until the user selects it.

Comment: Has there been any progress around having conversations being a part of the API? We noticed Conversations and ConversationThreads added as a part of the new groups API, but what about inbox, drafts and other non-group mail items?

Comment: any update on this is there any api to get messages grouped by conversations?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use this endpoint to cover both inbox and sentitems

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?$select=ConversationId & $filter=ConversationId eq '${params.conversationId}'
```